# Drawing balls w/o replacement

Tags: probability

Suppose we have $N$ balls of which $20$ are blue and the rest is red. Each have the same probability of being drawn.

What is the probability of drawing $k$ blue balls if I draw $1000$ times? Is it

$$\frac{\binom{20}{k}\binom{N}{1000-k}}{\binom{N}{1000}}$$ ?

What is the probability of drawing at least one blue ball? My guess is

$$\sum_{k=1}^{20}\frac{\binom{20}{k}\binom{N}{1000-k}}{\binom{N}{1000}}$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Small correction I believe - $\frac{{20 \choose k} {N-20 \choose 1000-k}}{{N \choose 1000}}$- Choosing $k$ blue balls and choosing $1000-k$ red balls from $N-20$ red balls. Second part follows from this.

Comment: Thankzzzz homey